# How could I calculate the Heat Index with low humidity?

Tags: temperature, weather, meteorology

The formula shown in the [Heat Index(HI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_index) requires that the relative humidity should be equal to or greater than 40%, so how to calculate the heat index when the humidity is less than 40%?

Or is there some other formulas can represent the "real feel temperature" without these limitation factors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the "Formula" section of that Wikipedia article again.  It gives a second set of coefficients which are good for humidities from 0-80%.

Comment: but it requires that "all temperatures between 70 and 115 °F", how to calculate the heat index when, say 53°F and 40% humidity?

Comment: Is the **heat** index even relevant in that situation?  The heat index is a measure of the human ability to regulate body temperature in various conditions.  Radiation alone is plenty of heat loss to maintain a good body temperature at a low temperature like 53 fahrenheit.  No one is going to feel hot at all in such circumstances...